# Have the code for video modal, It has a button as the trigger. I want to use simple text as the trigger

Tags: video, text, triggers, modal-dialog

This code works great to open a video. But it uses a button as the trigger. I need to fire it off with simple text instead of a button.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" 
 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
    
<body>
    
    <button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Play Video</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls width="100%">
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    

<script>

    $(function() {
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
    $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' video').load();
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});
        
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried removing all references to a button and replaced with simple html5 player. No go. Any help would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the button? You can use a normal span with the proper `data-` attributes, and it works the same.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <span class="video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Play Video</span>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls width="100%">
              <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".video").click(function() {
        var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
          videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
          videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
        $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal + ' video').load();
        $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function() {
          $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you.
And about the other thing, both sites look the same, and I suppose paths for all the imports/images are not working. Please post another question, someone will surely help you.